# objectDataSource updating - read only dictionary problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

```
protected void objUpdating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
{
    e.InputParameters.Add("update_name", "xxx");            
 }
```

Hi, I am trying to make Update method for ObjectDataSource, which has argument "update_name" but adding parameter to collection using add method throws an exception of dictionary ( key value ) is read only
any thougths?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Add method as ObjectDataSource has already added a parameter to the collection.

Try

```
e.InputParameters["update_name"]= "xxx";
```

that will work

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work
i am creating objectdatasource object programmaticaly in Page_Init, can that be a problem?